# asignar un valor a un dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlist

Estoy creando la vista edit de mi modelo equipos al cual desde el controlador mandare datos a la vista edit para poder visualizar y editar
Mi vista al recibir mi modelo los elementos de tipo DropDownList me piden una lista mas no un Valor entonces mando junto con el objeto un ViewBag con la lista soluionando ese inconveniente pero a la vez creandome un problema. al cargar mis datos las listas se muestran inicializadas

lo que quisiera es obtener esa lista en la posicion del valor que tenia el objeto

mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    
        Eq_tblEquipos eq_TblEquipos = db.Eq_tblEquipos.Find(id);
    



            ViewBag.Eq_tblUbicaciones_id = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblUbicaciones, "Id", "area",eq_TblEquipos.Eq_tblUbicaciones);
            ViewBag.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblTipoEquipos, "id", "NombreTipo", eq_TblEquipos.Eq_tblUbicaciones);

            return View(eq_TblEquipos);

}
```

y este es mi DropDownList de mi edit

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id, "Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en el segundo parametro pasa tu lista

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.Eq_tblMarcaEquipos_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Eq_tblUbicaciones_id, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte jorge luis